# Regular Expression notepad++ deleate comments in ( )

Tags: notepad++, html, find, find-and-replace

I am currently working with notepad++ and would like to deleate text between brackets togeather with the brackets themselves! I would like to use a regular expression.

Example:

```
(thisIsAnExample)
```

search and deleate (replace with nothing). `[^()]*` will search everything BETWEEN brackets, but not the brackets itselv. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one instead of `[^()]*`:

```
\(.*?\)
```

[EDITED - a small explanation]

Because the `(` and `)` are special characters and define a groups of characters, we need to **mask** them with `/`. There are a lot of very good RegEx tutorials online for example [this one](http://regexone.com/).

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.